# Limit sets of Kleinian groups

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Just wondering if there is some good reference (textbooks or expository papers) on Kleinian groups and limit sets? Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expository paper is [A Crash Course on Kleinian Groups](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masbb/Papers/50-trieste.pdf) by Caroline Series. The main reference for limit sets there is the following book:

D. Mumford, C. Series, D. Wright. Indra’s Pearls. Cambridge University Press, 2002.

But also the other references in this paper are interesting.